# Multi thread - openCV (imshow) - QMetaMethod error

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg

I create 2 threads with the function imshow(); from openCV 2.4.8, code as below:

```
void camera1 (string url)
{
  Mat img;
  ....
  imshow("camera1",img);
  waitkey(1);
  ....
}
void camera1 (string url)
{
  Mat img;
  ....
  imshow("camera2",img);
  waitkey(1);
  ....
}
int main ()
{
....
   thread Process1(camera1,url1);
   thread Process2(camera2,url2);
....
}
```

When the program is running, the terminal show that error: 
QMetaMethod::invoke: Unable to invoke methods with return values in queued connections

When I remove one of the imshow() functions the program work well.

Thank !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any interaction with the UI (getting key events, creating windows, drawing) should happen in the main thread, where the UI event loop runs. You can process data in background threads, but when it comes to `imshow` and `waitkey`, do them in the main thread only.